# Error arose when using Pkg.add() in Julia

Tags: package, julia

I have a problem when trying to add a package in the terminal using `Pkg.add`, the terminal gives me the following error message:

`````
fatal:your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
Error: failed process: Process(`git' --git-dir=````)
`````

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Gadfly. Installation failed and I couldn't load nor reinstall the package.

After looking at the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/packages/).
Turns out there is a cache folder (with the same name as the package) hidden in `Users\my_username\.julia\v0.4\.cache\` I removed this folder and the package installed fine from Julia running `Pkg.add("Gadfly")`.
Try removing the folder and install the package again.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more information about where this package comes from. Github? Your hard drive? A zip file?

If this is one of your packages, just create a commit.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
```

This should work.